# Storing local data for java application

Tags: java

My friend challenged me to make a  java application just like the "love test" mobile app. If you aren't familiar with this app you input two names(yours and someone else's) and it gives you the percentage of "compatibility". I want the random percentages to get saved so when they input the same names again it will display the same number.

Answer (score 3):

How about computing hash of the strings and computing a percentage based on some formula of your own using hash ? You get same value every time and no need to store value also.

Comment: I don't know how to do that I'm new at Java

Comment: Use the hashCode() method on each String, then you have two numbers that are produced in a way that the same string produces the same number.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Map<String, Double>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where the key is the concatenation of the names in alphabetic order, separated by a special character (i.e. `&`), and the value is the percentage.

In case you have to persist this data, you can serialize the Map, store it on disc, and recover it when you need it again.